# Cannot resolve method 'getUrl()'

Tags: android, android-imageview

Currently I am getting this error message "Cannot resolve method '**`getUrl()`**". Would you guys know why I'm getting this error?

Here is the code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(700,1200));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(4,4,4,4);
        /**
         * Using picasso to load the images.
         */
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movieItemLists.get(position).getUrl())
                .error(R.drawable.ic_error_placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_1)
                .into(image);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
        return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Whatever `movieItemLists.get()` returns does not have a `getUrl()` method. This has nothing to do with Picasso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `getUrl` method in the inner class .

`Sample`

```
public class YouClass{

public List<MovieItem> movieItemList;

private class MovieItem {
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
}
```